# Will replacing a .war without restarting tomcat cause any issues?

Tags: tomcat, war

I have a tomcat instance and when I add a new .war file, it automatically explodes the folder and deploys it. Now if I wanted to replace this webapp, do I simply delete the webapp folder and .war file? or do I need to restart tomcat as well?

I haven't experienced any particular symptoms yet, but would like to know what the community's experience has been and what to look out for. (does tomcat remove all traces of old webapp, including static variables, does it close database connections, etc?)

Answer (score 2):

My understanding is, assuming you have `antiJARLocking="true"` in your app's context.xml file, that you simply need to overwrite the war and Tomcat does the rest.  You should not have to restart Tomcat.  This is known as webapp hot deployment.

See also [standard implementation of Context](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/config/context.html#Standard_Implementation).